# JavaScript card game, how to compare cards in two strings?

Tags: javascript

I have been learning so much from this community. This is my first post here, I recently started learning coding.
 I am practicing JS by creating a simple card game played between Alec and Bob.
 Each player draws one card turn by turn from the deck. The player who draws the higher card wins the game.
 I am trying to find out how many games does Alec wins?

This is as far as I have done:

```
function solution(A, B) {

    var card1, card2;
    var alecWin = 0;

    var cards = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"];

    var alecCards = A.split("");
    var bobCards = B.split("");

    for(var i=0; i< alecCards.length; i++){
        for(var j=0; j< bobCards.length; j++){
            alecIndex = alecCards.indexOf(i);
            bobIndex = bobCards.indexOf(j);
            if(alecIndex > bobIndex){
                alecWin++;
            }
        } 
        return alecWin;
    }
}

solution("23JK45", "352Q8")
```

I want to return the number of games that Alec wins. Can anyone help me with this and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Use *one* loop rather than nested loops. Then, you want to check the index of each player's card in the `cards` array, so use:

```
  alecIndex = cards.indexOf(alecCards[i]);
  bobIndex = cards.indexOf(bobCards[i]); // use i, not j - same index
```

Then you can compare the indicies:

```js
function solution(A, B) {

  var card1, card2;
  var alecWin = 0;

  var cards = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"];

  var alecCards = A.split("");
  var bobCards = B.split("");

  for (var i = 0; i < alecCards.length; i++) {
      alecIndex = cards.indexOf(alecCards[i]);
      bobIndex = cards.indexOf(bobCards[i]);
      if (alecIndex > bobIndex) alecWin++;
  }

  return alecWin;

}

console.log(solution("23JK4", "352Q8"));
```

But this would be easier and quicker (less complexity) with an object or `Map`, indexed by card label, whose values is that card's index. Note that there's no need to convert the string to an array, `str[index]` works perfectly fine on strings:

```js
function solution(A, B) {
  const cards = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"];
  const cardObj = cards.reduce((a, label, i) => {
    a[label] = i;
    return a;
  }, {});
  let winCount = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (cardObj[A[i]] > cardObj[B[i]]) winCount++;
  }
  return winCount;
}

console.log(solution("23JK4", "352Q8"));
```

Also note that you should fix your input: both input strings should be the *same* length for a meaningful result.